# Hey... how would you say “Be true, be you” in korean

Tags: translation

Sooo a friend of mine wants a tattoo and wants to tattoo something in korean... I would translate it myself but I don’t really trust myself and my knowledge in Korean... Still a starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest :

- 너답게 살라 (live like yourself)
- 진실되게, 스스로가 되어라 (direct translation)

But don't let him tattoo with 굴림 font, instead use some other looking nicer fonts. 굴림 looks hilarious as tattoo.

Answer (score 1):

This is beyond a simple word-for-word translation and it's more like copywriting. Since this is a tatoo we're talking about, we don't want any awkward Korean that sounds translated or stiff. 
The best I can come up with is '나답게, 진실하게' (the order is changed to Be you>be true, just because it sounded better to me, but these can be reversed). It also rhymes. I don't recommend using passive forms in Korean - avoid it as much as you can. Don't use 진실되게 which is passive.